# How do LLVM iterators get referenced?

Tags: c++, iterator, llvm

I'm working on upgrading an old project from LLVM 3.0 to 7.0.0. I read in the [LLVM 4.0.0 Relesae Notes](https://releases.llvm.org/4.0.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html):

> `iterator` now stores an `ilist_node_base*` instead of a `T*`. The implicit conversions between `ilist<T>::iterator` and `T*` have been removed. Clients may use `N->getIterator()` (if not nullptr) or `&*I` (if not end())

I've now run into a few instances in which dereferencing an iterator via `&*i` is allowed by the compiler, but I'm totally stumped on how/why this works. From my understanding of pointers, shouldn't `&*i == i`?

A specific example (this code was valid using LLVM 3.0):

```
for (Function::iterator b = function.begin(), be = function.end(); b != be; b++)
{
    for (BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin(), ie=b->end(); i != ie; i++)
    {
        ...
        CallInst::Create(module.getFunction("foo"), args, "", i);
    }
}
```

When run with LLVM 7.0.0 gives the error:

```
error: no matching function for call 'Create'

/root/llvm-7.0.0/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1941.20: note: candidate function not viable: no known 
      conversion from 'BasicBlock::iterator'(aka 'ilist_iterator<node_options<llvm::Instruction,
      extract_sentinel_tracking<>::value, extract_sentinel_tracking<>::is_explicit, void>, false,
      false>') to 'llvm::Instruction *' for 4th argument
```

But the following compiles just fine and understands that `&*i` is a `instruction*`:

```
for (Function::iterator b = function.begin(), be = function.end(); b != be; b++)
{
    for (BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin(), ie=b->end(); i != ie; i++)
    {
        ...
        CallInst::Create(module.getFunction("foo"), args, "", &*i);
    }
}
```

I've looked around but haven't found a good explanation of this change. Could anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Is `&*b` a recommended practice? I guess it is not, but what is the other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `*i`, you actually call special `operator*()` overload, that returns an `Instruction` for you, and then you get a pointer to it with `&`. Hence, `&*i`.

Comment: That is deceptively simple, thanks! Do you happen to have a source for the overloaded `operator*()`?